# Spring endpoint to endpoint using RestTemplate Exception handling

Tags: java, spring, rest, exception

We have a microservice architecture. Each service exposing data through Rest. All controllers are set up using Spring:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "foobar")
public class UiController {

      @PostMapping("foo")
      public ResponseEntity<Foo> addFoo(@RequestBody final FooDto fooDto) {

           Foo fromDb = adminService.addFoo(converterToModel.convert(fooDto);
           return ResponseEntity.ok(converterToDto.convert(fromDb));

      }
```

If for some reason fooDto can't be added to the database. A custom Exception is thrown:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
public class FooAlreadyAssignedException extends RuntimeException {

    public FooAlreadyAssignedException(String msg) {
        super("The following foos are already assigned to foobar: " + msg);
    }

}
```

In Postman you see the following JSON after the Exception above is thrown

```
{
    "timestamp": 1508247298817,
    "status": 409,
    "error": "Conflict",
    "exception": "com.foo.exception.FooCodeAlreadyExistsException",
    "message": "A foo with code: foo already exists",
    "path": "/foo/foobar"
}
```

We have 4 different services like these all set up the same way.

Our UI is made in Angular 4 and makes REST calls to our Gateway. The Gateway is the connection between the microservices and the UI. It also exposes a REST endpoint. It's also implemented with Spring. I added a picture for clarification:

[architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmpDO.png)

"edit: I see that I didn't complete the arrows. Of course all data is passed back up to the UI"

**The problem**

The Gateway uses a RestTemplate to call the APIs of the microservices
when a custom Exception is thrown in the microservice the Gateway returns this:

```
{
"timestamp": "2017-10-16T15:30:03.456Z",
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"exception": "org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException",
"message": "409 null",
"path": "/v1/printstations"
}
```

My original response a HttpStatus.conflict (status = 409) seems to be wrapped in a status 500 message by the Gateway. I don't want this behavior, I want it to pass the original message to the UI.

Any ideas on how to control this behavior?

**Notes**

I have tested with Postman that if you access the microservice directly it returns the 409 with the message written in the custom Exception

I have already tried overriding Springs ResponseErrorHandler but was not able to find a suitable solution that way.

Comment: So, what's the code of the gateway?

Comment: As I said it's setup with Spring (thus the same as the microservices) but uses a RestTemplate to call the APIs of the microservices

Answer (score 1):

In gateway code where spring rest template is calling your microservices, I would recommend catching HttpClientErrorException and then create your own exception class like ApiException as in below example, this way you will be able to pass the exact exception which is thrown from the microservices:

```
catch (org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException e) {

            throw new ApiException(e.getMessage(), e, e.getRawStatusCode(), e.getResponseHeaders(),
                    e.getResponseBodyAsString(), fullURIPath, null);
        }
```

where ApiException has a constructor like below:

```
public ApiException(String message, Throwable throwable, int code, Map<String, List<String>> responseHeaders,
            String responseBody, String requestURI, String requestBody) {
        super(message, throwable);
        this.code = code;
        this.responseHeaders = responseHeaders;
        this.responseBody = responseBody;
        this.requestURI = requestURI;
        this.requestBody = requestBody;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I tried out your solution but this resulted in an error in the same format.

Answer (score 1):

Issue can be closed.

The solution was to map the exception that happened in the microservice to a valid ResponseEntity in the Gateway, so that the RestTemplate in the Gateway wouldn't repackage the error in a 500 server error.

We did this by creating a @ControllerAdvice class

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler(value = {HttpClientErrorException.class})
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleConflict(HttpClientErrorException ex, WebRequest request) {

    return handleExceptionInternal(ex, ex.getResponseBodyAsString(),
            new HttpHeaders(), ex.getStatusCode(), request);

    }

}
```

This results in a ResponseEntity with the correct HttpStatus from the Exception in the microservice and a JSON body containing the message needed by the front-end.